# Editing Excel from Access VBA Object Required Error

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a program that opens an Excel spreadsheet and makes changes to it. I am always editing the first sheet but if it is a certain type of report I want to edit the second sheet as well. This all works fine for me on the first sheet and all but centering the text in the cell on the second sheet. I get an Object Required error only when I try to do this. I center the text in the cells on the first sheet no problem. The error only comes after I pass the object to the new procedure. Here is some of my code:

First Procedure

```
Private Sub OSummary1(strfile As String, strTableResults As String, dtUnivDt As Date)
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim objWorkbook As Object
Dim objSheet As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strfile)
Set objSheet = objWorkbook.Sheets(1)
```

Later in the code

```
ElseIf Mid(strTableResults, 11, 1) = 1 Then
    Max = 11
    Do Until i > Max
        If .Cells(i, 4).Value = "0" And .Cells(i, 2).Value = "0" And .Cells(i, 3).Value = "0" Then
            .Cells(i, 4).Value = "NA"
            .Cells(i, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = "-"
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = "-"
        ElseIf .Cells(i, 2).Value = "0" Then
            .Cells(i, 4).Value = "0.0"
            .Cells(i, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
        ElseIf .Cells(i, 4).Value >= "95.00" Or .Cells(i, 4).Value = "100" Then
            .Cells(i, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
        ElseIf .Cells(i, 4).Value >= "90.00" And .Cells(i, 4).Value < "95.00" Then
            .Cells(i, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        Else
            .Cells(i, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
        End If
        
        If .Cells(i, 4).Value = 0 Then
            .Cells(i, 4).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        ElseIf Not .Cells(i, 4).Value Like "*.*" Then
            .Cells(i, 4).NumberFormat = "#.00""%"""
        ElseIf .Cells(i, 4).Value Like "*.#" Then
            .Cells(i, 4).NumberFormat = "#.#0""%"""
        Else
            .Cells(i, 4).NumberFormat = "#.##""%"""
        End If
                    
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "AppealNotificationTimeliness" Then
            .Cells(i, 1).Font.Bold = True
            .Cells(i, 2).Font.Bold = True
            .Cells(i, 3).Font.Bold = True
            .Cells(i, 4).Font.Bold = True
            .Cells(i, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Cells(i, 3).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Cells(i, 4).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            iB = Len(.Cells(i, 2).Value)
            iC = Len(.Cells(i, 3).Value)
            iD = .Cells(i, 4).Value
        Else
            'Indent header
            .Cells(i, 1).IndentLevel = 3
            'Indent sub-headers
            If iB < 3 Then
                .Cells(i, 2).IndentLevel = 5
            ElseIf iB > 2 And iB < 5 Then
                .Cells(i, 2).IndentLevel = 4
            ElseIf iB > 4 And iB < 7 Then
                .Cells(i, 2).IndentLevel = 3
            Else
                .Cells(i, 2).IndentLevel = 2
            End If
            
            If iC < 3 Then
                .Cells(i, 3).IndentLevel = 4
            ElseIf iC > 2 And iC < 5 Then
                .Cells(i, 3).IndentLevel = 3
            ElseIf iC > 4 And iC < 7 Then
                .Cells(i, 3).IndentLevel = 2
            Else
                .Cells(i, 3).IndentLevel = 1
            End If
            
            If iD = "NA" Then
                .Cells(i, 4).IndentLevel = 5
            ElseIf iD = "100" Then
                .Cells(i, 4).IndentLevel = 3
            Else
                .Cells(i, 4).IndentLevel = 4
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    If Right(strTableResults, 3) = "FDR" Then
        Call FDRTable1(objWorkbook)
    End If
```

**This all works fine for sheet 1**

Second Procedure from Call above

```
 Private Sub FDRTable1(ByRef objWorkbook As Object)
 Dim objSheet As Object
 Dim RowCnt As Integer
 Dim CurrentRow As Integer
 Dim CurrentRowVal As String
 Dim iRange As Range
 Dim iCells As Range
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim Max As Integer

 Set objSheet = objWorkbook.Sheets(2)

 i = 2

With objSheet
'Header
.Cells(1, 1).Font.Size = 12
.Range("A1:G1").Font.Bold = True
.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
.Range("A2:G6").BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium
.Range("A7:G9").BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium
.Range("A10:G14").BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium
.Range("A15:G17").BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium

Max = 17
Do Until i > Max
    If .Cells(i, 7).Value = "0" And .Cells(i, 4).Value = "0" And .Cells(i, 6).Value = "0" Then
        .Cells(i, 7).Value = "NA"
        .Cells(i, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        .Cells(i, 4).Value = "-"
        .Cells(i, 5).Value = "-"
        .Cells(i, 6).Value = "-"
    ElseIf .Cells(i, 4).Value = "0" Then
        .Cells(i, 7).Value = "0.0"
        .Cells(i, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
    ElseIf .Cells(i, 7).Value >= "95.00" Or .Cells(i, 7).Value = "100" Then
        .Cells(i, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
    ElseIf .Cells(i, 7).Value >= "90.00" And .Cells(i, 7).Value < "95.00" Then
        .Cells(i, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
    Else
        .Cells(i, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
    End If
    
    If .Cells(i, 7).Value = 0 Then
        .Cells(i, 7).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        .Cells(i, 4).HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter
        .Cells(i, 5).HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter
        .Cells(i, 6).HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter
        .Cells(i, 7).HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter
    ElseIf Not .Cells(i, 7).Value Like "*.*" Then
        .Cells(i, 7).NumberFormat = "#.00""%"""
        .Cells(i, 4).HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter
        .Cells(i, 5).HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter
        .Cells(i, 6).HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter
        .Cells(i, 7).HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter
    ElseIf .Cells(i, 7).Value Like "*.#" Then
        .Cells(i, 7).NumberFormat = "#.#0""%"""
        .Cells(i, 4).HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter
        .Cells(i, 5).HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter
        .Cells(i, 6).HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter
        .Cells(i, 7).HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter
    Else
        .Cells(i, 7).NumberFormat = "#.##""%"""
        .Cells(i, 4).HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter
        .Cells(i, 5).HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter
        .Cells(i, 6).HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter
        .Cells(i, 7).HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
End With

End Sub
```

**This all works too except I get the error when I try to center the text (.HorizontalAlignment.xlCenter). If I remove those lines, it works fine.**

Comment: Should be `.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter`, but if you're late-binding Excel, add `Const xlCenter As Long = -4108` too.

Comment: OMG, I can't believe I missed that!!! Thank you so much.

Comment: ... when in doubt, the macro recorder in Excel can be helpful.